# Regex to find last occurrence with optional choice

Tags: regex

I have this string

```
<p class="p1">lalala</p><div><div class="div2"><div><p>lalala22</p></div></div></div>
```

I want to find `<div>` or `<div .*?>` whichever the last one

I tried with this regex

```
(<div>|<div .*?>)(?!.*(<div>|<div .*?>))
```

and

```
(<div>(?!.*<div>)|<div .*?>(?!.*<div .*?>))
```

but it will always end up finding `<div class="div2">` instead of the last one which is `<div>`

How to solve this? How to use negative lookahead with optional choice like this?

EDIT
to make it clear, the end result of regex that I want is `<div><p>lalala22</p></div>`, that's why I want to find the last starting div tag

Comment: Any reason not to use a parser? E.g. `BeautifulSoup`, `lxml`, etc.?

Comment: Currently already familiar with this tool, as all of my projects are created with this tool. Sure I'll try to use different tool in the future to variate it. I have my eye on Selenium, but I'll take a look at your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this simple regex to capture the last occurence of `<div>` tag. This works whether `<div>` tag has any attributes or not.

```
.*(<div[^>]*>.*?<\/div>)
```

**Explanation:**

- `.*` --> Match anything greedily till you encounter `<div` tag which means it matches everything except last div tag
- `<div[^>]*>` --> This matches the div tag optionally having any attributes
- `.*?` --> Matches any text non-greedily and stops just before a closing div tag
- `<\/div>` --> Matches a closing div tag

[Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/zkuJ1j/1)

In case you want the regex to just match the last `<div>` tag, you can use `\K` operator to reset whatever matched that you don't want to get included in full match, and change the regex to this,

```
.*\K(<div[^>]*>.*?<\/div>)
```

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/zkuJ1j/2)

Let me know if this works good for you.

Comment: Well, you did it man, thanks, this is what I wanted! I never know about \K before!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: The `\K` is the key I haven't been aware of. Good job and thanks too for a lesson :)

Comment: @Nikolas: Yes brother, `\K` is a very useful operator where it really helps when we want to do look behinds and can't quantify, `\K` comes for the resque :)

Comment: For finding last match, between this using `\K` and compared to negative lookahead, `\K` is much better, it even can use `or` https://regex101.com/r/zkuJ1j/3 Now, why do we need negative lookahead?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, Regex is a great tool, however not for the XML/HTML parsing. I recommend you to use a programming language and the proper tools to parse a DOM-based file and get the last `<div>`.

If you insist to stick with Regex for such a simple case, here is a Regex to find the last `<div>` (both with or without a class) and its content:

```
.*(<div(?:\s+class="[^>]*"\s*)?>.*?<\/div>).*
```

Try it out at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Sz1MTa/2).

1. The idea starts to match the last `<div>`, its content until the first `</div>` with `.*(<div>.*?<\/div>).*` - this is fairly easy, however, it matches the nested divs as well. Let's define what can be inside the matched `div`.
2. `(?:\s+class="[^>]*"\s*)` is an optional non-capturing group which defines the div can contain class(es).
3. The calculation is quite long - takes 716 steps at my example for 4 usages. You might want to use a programing language to achieve better and more stable results.

---

If you want the full match to contain the result only. You have to use the positive look behind and find the previous content - yet this is a bit restrictive ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rhImWq/1)) because the solution is based on the fact, that there 
 is always `"div2">` located before it:

```
(?<="div2">)(<div(?:\s+class="[^>]*"\s*)?>.*?<\/div>)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your answer partially work, as the Group 1 capture is what I want, but the full capture is wrong. How to change the Group 1 capture as the answer for full match?

Comment: What exactly do you want to match in your sample? `lalala22`?

Comment: the end result from my regex will be `<div><p>lalala22</p></div>`, that's why I want the last `<div>` or `<div .*?>` for starting point

Comment: It's still not clear. Do you want to match `<div><p>lalala22</p></div>` or `lalala22` or just the last `<div>` only?

Comment: This one `<div><p>lalala22</p></div>`

Comment: The full match captures all the context that is needed and the extraction works with the groups itself. The wanted result is available in the first group.

Comment: I've been playing regex for a while but I still need a lot to learn, unless your "full match" answer is `<div><p>lalala22</p></div>` I can't use it.

Comment: If you provide the name of a tool or a programming language, I might help more. This seems as an XY problem - what exactly, why and where you want to capture the last `div`?

Comment: The tool is Zennoposter, its regex engine seems to be pcre. I'm going to use to to parse web page.

Comment: See my edited answer. To parse a webpage, I recommend u to use the way different tools.

Comment: This won't work `(?<="div2">)(<div(?:\s+class="[^>]*"\s*)?>.*?<\/div>)` because it's basing on static object `"div2">` Well it seems I have to find some round trip... :) Thanks for the help